# Why does first-child / last-child not work on blockquote

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

It might be a stupid question, but why is first-child / lastchild not working on the blockquotes?

**CSS**

```
p { margin: 0 0 1.6em 0; }
blockquote { margin: 0; padding: 0 25px 1em; background-color: #CCC; border-left: 5px solid #333; }
blockquote:first-child { padding-top: 25px; color: red; }
blockquote:last-child { padding-bottom: 25px; margin-bottom: 1em; color: yellow; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <p>Integer bibendum erat ipsum, ac sodales nisi suscipit ut. Nullam eu felis quis nisl consectetur vehicula vel vitae justo. Praesent ullamcorper pretium posuere. Aliquam in suscipit nisi. Suspendisse potenti. In sed ligula vitae libero gravida molestie eu in nisl. Etiam ornare ultrices dolor, id consequat orci fringilla non. Nam ultrices mauris rutrum, fringilla ligula nec, aliquet turpis. Proin turpis velit, dictum vel vehicula vitae, scelerisque a sapien.</p>
    <blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</blockquote>
    <blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</blockquote>
    <blockquote>Nunc scelerisque, risus id tempor viverra, ante nibh pulvinar neque, non volutpat ante tellus facilisis justo. Donec eget auctor ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec rhoncus lacus eget arcu suscipit vulputate. Sed at aliquet elit, in vestibulum metus. Nulla pharetra nibh quam, a ullamcorper nunc interdum sed. Etiam aliquam purus quis orci tincidunt malesuada. Etiam metus quam, gravida id molestie sit amet, suscipit eget leo.</blockquote>
    <p>Integer bibendum erat ipsum, ac sodales nisi suscipit ut. Nullam eu felis quis nisl consectetur vehicula vel vitae justo. Praesent ullamcorper pretium posuere. Aliquam in suscipit nisi. Suspendisse potenti. In sed ligula vitae libero gravida molestie eu in nisl. Etiam ornare ultrices dolor, id consequat orci fringilla non. Nam ultrices mauris rutrum, fringilla ligula nec, aliquet turpis. Proin turpis velit, dictum vel vehicula vitae, scelerisque a sapien.</p>
    <blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</blockquote>
    <blockquote>Nunc scelerisque, risus id tempor viverra, ante nibh pulvinar neque, non volutpat ante tellus facilisis justo. Donec eget auctor ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec rhoncus lacus eget arcu suscipit vulputate. Sed at aliquet elit, in vestibulum metus. Nulla pharetra nibh quam, a ullamcorper nunc interdum sed. Etiam aliquam purus quis orci tincidunt malesuada. Etiam metus quam, gravida id molestie sit amet, suscipit eget leo.</blockquote>
</div>
```

Update: What I want in this example:

- blockquote 1: red
- blockquote 2: default color
- blockquote 3: yellow
- blockquote 4: red
- blockquote 5: yellow

[JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NyzLA/1/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)/[`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type). As the name of the pseudo class implies, this will style the first/last of the element *type*.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/G8Kvg/)

```
blockquote:first-of-type {
    padding-top: 25px;
}
blockquote:last-of-type {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the :first-of-type pseudo class. But this is not exactly what I need (see updated question).

Comment: @klaasjansen Based on your updated, it seems like you would rather use `:nth-of-type`.. http://jsfiddle.net/e24tC/ It fits the new requirements, but might not work so well with dynamic content.

Comment: Like I said though, that obviously wouldn't work for dynamic content.. due to CSS limitations, i'd therefore suggest changing the markup and simply doing **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/SpTwp/)**.. another alternative that doesn't require a markup change would be **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Gp8fA/)**.. not the greatest, but i'm just showing some options.. `:first`/`:last`-`of-type` solved the initial question though..

Comment: I think I can use the last example, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because they're not the first child or last child, the first child here is the `p` element.

To target the first `blockquote`, you may do

```
:not(blockquote) + blockquote {
```

Comment: Is there a way to target the first and last blockquote in a row in css?

(i'm stuck to this code due to my wysiwyg editor)

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @klaasjansen Use the other answer. Mine works well for first in sequence (see http://jsfiddle.net/etJsW/) but doesn't let you target the last in sequence (it has the advantage to let you target the first of type *in a sequence* though). Those are things that CSS doesn't solve well yet (it will be better soon).